# How to switch between two activities in an Android app automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two `Activities`

1. rfidReader
2. onTravel

When I read RFID card on `rfidReader` activity and pressing GoNext Button takes me to `onTravel` activity and calculates startingLocation (latitude, longitude) and go back to previous activity (rfidReader) automatically after sometime. (Ex: 5 second)

Then again when I read the same RFID card I need to go to the `onTravel` Activity and this time it will calculate the location as destination location and distance traveled.

So how it can be done to switch between them automatically after sometime (for example 5 sec).

```
public void onClickcard(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, onTravel.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, input);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is my function of onTravel activity where I want to switch back to previous activity (rfidreader) after showing the messages.

```
public void GoBack(int current_balance)
{ 
if(current_balance>10)
    {   
     textView.setText("Thank you,you are eligible for travelling....");
    }
else{
     textView.setText("Sorry,you are not eligible for travelling this 
     time.Please recharge your card..");
    }
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, rfidreader.class);
  startActivity(intent);    
}
```

There are so many posts regarding activity switching but I am unable to find any regarding scheduled activity switching.

Comment: This is answered many times before on StackOverflow. Search for Intents

Answer (score 0):

Set `launchMode`  of Activities to `singleInstance` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Probably it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit Intent doesn't specifiy the component. In such case, intent provides information of available components provided by the system that is to be invoked.

For example, you may write the following code to view the webpage.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.javatpoint.com"));  
startActivity(intent);
```

Explicit Intent specifies the component. In such case, intent provides the external class to be invoked.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  
startActivity(i);
```